# homeomorphism of complement of union of two lines in $\Bbb C^2$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Consider two lines $A$ and $B$ in $\Bbb C^2$ intersecting in one point.

Let's denote C and D respectively the lines $X=0$ and $Y=0$ in $\Bbb C^2$.

Let $X = \Bbb C^2 \setminus (A \cup B)$.

prove that X is homeomorphic to $\{(x,y) \in \Bbb C^2 : xy\ne 0\}$.

I tried to do the following:

let $z\in X$. I try to build an homeomorphism from $X$ to $\Bbb C^2\setminus (C \cup D)$.

Translation is an homeomorphism in $\Bbb C^2$ so we can suppose that $A$ and $B$ intersect in the origin of $\Bbb C^2$.

Now I have four lines $A, B, C, D$ intersecting at the origin of $\Bbb C^2$, so we can consider building a homeomorphism : $X\to \Bbb C^2\setminus (C \cup D) $ using a rotation, but then A and B won't rotate with the same angle to map respectively to C and D?

Thank you for any help, comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're also allowed to *shear*, in addition to translating and rotating.  So you will be done if you can find a linear isomorphism $\phi \in GL(\mathbb{C}^2)$ that takes the lines $D$ and $C$ to the lines $A$ and $B$.  This is easy to do.  Let $A$ be the span of $(a_1, a_2)$ and $B$ be the span of $(b_1, b_2)$.  Then the transformation $$\phi = \begin{pmatrix} a_1 & b_1 \\ a_2 & b_2 \end{pmatrix}$$ takes $D$, which is the span of $(1,0)$, to $A$ and $C$ to $B$.  Moreover, $\phi$ is invertible since it takes a basis to a a basis.